# AutoComplete list showing bullets

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, textbox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a `TextBox` with an Ajax Control Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender, and I'm having some issues with the formatting.

If I omit the `CompletionListCssClass`, `CompletionListItemCssClass`, `CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass` values, it displays fine.  But I just need to align the autocomplete text to the left, and the size of the `TextBox`.

If I set these values in the site.css:

```
.autocomplete_listItem
{
    background-color: #222;
    color: #cfdbe6;
}

.autocomplete_highlightedListItem
{
    background-color: #999;
    color: #111;
}

.autocomplete_completionListElement
{

}
```

then I bullets on the list.

How do I make the bullets not show, align the list to be right under the `TextBox`, the list items left aligned, and the size to match the `TextBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do to remove the bullets is add `list-style-type:none` to each of your classes:

```
.autocomplete_listItem
{
    background-color: #222;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.autocomplete_highlightedListItem
{
    background-color: #999;
    color: #111;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.autocomplete_completionListElement
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

This is because the autocomplete results are returned as a bulleted list by the AJAX extender - so if you customize the style, you need to make sure and hide those bullets.

In order to tell you how to align it properly with other elements, I would need to see your markup (which is not included in your question).

Comment: Actually without the bullets the layout is perfect. Thanks